# Disabling the web interface of a filtering program

Tags: networking, user-interface, internet-filter

I am using K9 Web Protection at home, which does a great job filtering internet content. Everything is controlled via the web interface which is available at the address **127.0.0.1:2372** . However, everytime a website is blocked, the user is redirected to this page. What I would like to do is that no redirection to the interface happen. That would make any attempt to bypass the program much harder - simply because one would not even know what the program is ! So what are my possibilities ?

Would blocking the port 2372 in the Windows firewall be a workable solution ?

**Note :**

The web interface looks like this :

[image: K9 Web Protection's user interface]

One thing that I have tried was to edit the executable *k9filter.exe* using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). I appended

> self|window|document.location.replace('127.0.0.1');

to the javascript file inside it. However, this causes stability issues.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If K9 does allow for this sort of configuration find software that does. Blocking the port would not change the behavior of K9 in the slighest.

Comment: I don't know of any program that does as good a filtering as K9 does, unfortunately.

Comment: I would contact K9 on how to disable being redirected to the configuration page.  A normal user being redirected to the configuration page does not sound right.  I could accept some sort of K9 page, you won't get around that, if I am correct.

Comment: The page I am redirected to does prompt for a password if I wish to change anything... But that doesn't help me very much.

Comment: If you actually set it to `document.location.replace('127.0.0.1');` then does setting it to `document.location.replace('http://127.0.0.1');` help any? Exactly what kind of "Stability" issues did making this change cause?

Comment: The trick that I mention does work and it's almost perfect. The only issue I have found so far is that the program needs more time to start up. So when I just start my computer, I don't immediately get an internet connection. Instead I have this message for 3/4 minutes : "K9 Web Protection service not available" which quite disturbs me...